# Summation of product of gaussian and negative variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $\vec\theta$ satisfying for $\forall i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, $\sum_{j}A_{ij} \sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0$. $A$ denotes a symmetric, diagonal-zero, random matrix.

Denote the $i,j$ satisfying $\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)<0$ as $i^*,j^*$.

**My question** What condition on random matrix $A$ such that we can obtain

$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i^*,j^*}A_{ij}\cos(\theta_{i^*}-\theta_{j^*})<0)$$ grows with $n$?

**What I tried** It seems the condition '$\forall i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, $\sum_{j}A_{ij} \sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0$' is not useful. Thus I simplify the problem to the following.

Suppose $a_i<0$ for all $I$ are negative scalars, and $X_i$ denote iid random variables.

What condition we can put on the distribution of $X_i$ such that the probability of event $$\sum_i a_iX_i<0$$ grows with
$n$?